# D3.js area chart loading in specific color

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have this area chart going on and I am trying to do a specific color scale with it.

I am not getting any errors in my console so i am assuming i'm loading in the data right something just might be in the wrong place.

I am curious to see what you have to say i am not sure where to go from here. Thank you.

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 80, right: 25, bottom: 30, left: 40},
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nataliemcg18/Data/master/NASA_Surface_Temperature.csv",

  // When reading the csv, I must format variables:
  function(d){
    return { variable : d3.timeParse("%Y")(d.variable), value : d.value }
  },

  // Now I can use this dataset:
  function(data) {

    // Add X axis --> it is a date format
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.variable; }))
      .range([ 0, width ]);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([-1.2, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.value; })])
      .range([ height, -10 ]);
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

     var myColor = d3.scaleSequential()
    .interpolator( d3.interpolateRdYlBu)
    .domain([1.40, -.80])

    // Add the area
    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", d=>myColor())
      .attr("stroke", "#69b3a2")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", d3.area()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.variable) })
        .y0(y(0))
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
        )

})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what colour you're tryng to change here - is it the fill color (of which there is only one for a given path)? Can you add an example of what you're trying to achieve eg. a picture?

Comment: var myColor = d3.scaleSequential()
    .interpolator( d3.interpolateRdYlBu)
    .domain([1.40, -.80])    It is a fade from red to yellow to blue depending on the domain

Comment: sorry, do you want a gradient fill? - remember there can be only 1 fill color. Or do you want each point to have a bar of colour below/above it? Check this out for some ideas: https://www.freshconsulting.com/d3-js-gradients-the-easy-way/ A quick picture might be the best way to explain this one